# Removing/Editing Fragments that were add dynamically:

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have this situation:

I have an Activity in which I add `Fragment`s dynamically and the result looks like this:

[image]

**Explanation:**

**Yellow:** `TextView` inside of a `Fragment`

**Orange:** Images `Fragment`

**Blue:** `ImageView`'s inside of a `Fragment`

Here is the code for adding the fragments:

```
     fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction newfragmentTransaction;
     for (Comment tempComment : taskCommentList)
     {
         Bundle commentBundle = new Bundle();
         CommentFragment commentFragment = new CommentFragment();
         commentString = tempComment.getText();
         if (tempComment.isPictureFirst())
         {
             if (tempComment.getPictureFilesList().size() > 0)
             {
                 picturesFragment = new PicturesFragment();
                 Bundle picturesBundle = new Bundle();
                 ArrayList<String> picturesStringPathsList = new ArrayList<String>();
                 for (File tempFile : tempComment.getPictureFilesList())
                 {
                     picturesStringPathsList.add(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
                 }
                 picturesBundle.putStringArrayList(PICTURES_PATHS, picturesStringPathsList);
                 picturesFragment.setArguments(picturesBundle);
                 newfragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                 newfragmentTransaction.add(R.id.containerForFragments, picturesFragment).commit();                 
             }
             if (commentString != "")
             {
                    commentBundle.putString("comment", commentString);
                    commentBundle.putString("user", tempComment.getUser());
                    commentBundle.putString("at", tempComment.getTime()+", "+tempComment.getDate());
                    commentFragment.setArguments(commentBundle);
                    newfragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    newfragmentTransaction
                    .add(R.id.containerForFragments, commentFragment, "comment"+ String.valueOf(taskCommentList.indexOf(tempComment)))
                    .commit();                  
             }
         }
         else
         {
             if (commentString != "")
             {
                    commentBundle.putString("comment", commentString);
                    commentBundle.putString("user", tempComment.getUser());
                    commentBundle.putString("at", tempComment.getTime()+", "+tempComment.getDate());
                    commentFragment.setArguments(commentBundle);
                    newfragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    newfragmentTransaction
                    .add(R.id.containerForFragments, commentFragment, "comment"+ String.valueOf(taskCommentList.indexOf(tempComment)))
                    .commit();                  
             }

             if (tempComment.getPictureFilesList().size() > 0)
             {
                 picturesFragment = new PicturesFragment();
                 Bundle picturesBundle = new Bundle();
                 ArrayList<String> picturesStringPathsList = new ArrayList<String>();
                 for (File tempFile : tempComment.getPictureFilesList())
                 {
                     picturesStringPathsList.add(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
                 }
                 picturesBundle.putStringArrayList(PICTURES_PATHS, picturesStringPathsList);
                 picturesFragment.setArguments(picturesBundle);
                 newfragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                 newfragmentTransaction.add(R.id.containerForFragments, picturesFragment).commit();                 
             }
         }
     }
```

**The problem:** Now I need to add an edit and delete options for each one of those Fragments. 
Until now I was making transactions and "throwing" my fragments inside of my `Activity` main view.
Now I have to get hold of each and every one of fragment instances I have created (Maybe create an array of them?), or is there another way? Maybe using the Fragment Manager?

**UPDATE:**
Following the preposition here I did the following:

**1.** I have defined a `getFragmentTag` and `setFragmentTag` in my used fragments.
So when I add the fragment via `FragmentManager` I do this:

```
     String tempTag = commentTagString+currentCommentFragmentTagNumber;
     currentCommentFragmentTagNumber++;
     commentFragment.setFragmentTag(tempTag);
     newfragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     newfragmentTransaction.add(R.id.containerForFragments, commentFragment, tempTag).commit();
```

in each fragment I have `ImageView`s for editing and deleting the fragment:

```
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="pictureFragmentEditOnClick"
        android:src="@drawable/add_comment_button"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/add_comment_button" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iRemove"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="pictureFragmentRemoveOnClick"
        android:src="@drawable/add_comment_button"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/add_comment_button" />
```

So in My main `FramgnetActivity` I do this to get the fragment tag:

```
PicturesFragment tempFragment = (PicturesFragment)v.getParent().getParent();
String tempTag = tempFragment.getFragmentTag();
Log.d(TAG, "The Fragments tag is: "+ tempTag);
```

but for some reason I receive a casting error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout cannot be cast to com.emildesign.sgtaskmanager.fragments.CommentFragment
```

**So The Question is:** how do I get this tag I associated to the fragment?

another question is if I delete one of the middle fragment would the empty space that created be removed and the bottom fragments will "slide" up to cover it?

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the instance of the fragment that the `ImageView` was clicked in I did the following:

in the Fragment I set two `onClickListeners` for both of the images like this:

```
    iEdit = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.iEdit);
    iEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "pressed edit button");
            ((PicturesAndCommentsActivity) getActivity()).commentFragmentEditOnClick(fragmentTag);
        }
    });

    iRemove = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.iRemove);
    iRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "pressed remove button");
            ((PicturesAndCommentsActivity) getActivity()).commentFragmentRemoveOnClick(fragmentTag);
        }
    });
```

and in the fragment activity I defined those two methods like this:

```
public void commentFragmentRemoveOnClick (String tag)
{
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.remove(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)).commit();
}
```

for removing the fragment, and Now I'm working on editing the fragment.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to retrieve fragments is to assign a tag to them using [add(containerId,fragment,tag)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) to add the fragment with a unique tag, then using [findFragmentByTag(tag)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve it.

Comment: if you look carefully at the code I posted you see: .add(R.id.containerForFragments, commentFragment, "comment"+ String.valueOf(taskCommentList.indexOf(tempComment))). So I'm well aware of the tag option. but how would you suggest to connect between a certain edit/delete button that was pushed in one of the fragments and the tags?

Comment: You can certainly pass in the tag to the Fragment's Bundle, then pass that tag back to the Activity via a callback if the Activity is managing the edit/delete process. More details at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: if I delete one of the middle fragment would the empty space that created be removed and the bottom fragments will "slide" up to cover it?

Comment: I have followed you advice but for some reason I cant get the fragment tag out of the fragment, do you have any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: @EmilAdz - `Fragment`s aren't added to your layout, so you can't use `View.getParent()` to retrieve information from the fragment. I would remove your `onClick` XML attributes for each button and instead use `setOnClickListener` within each Fragment. That way, the call sequence goes ImageView->Fragment->FragmentActivity, rather than skipping the Fragment (which knows the relationship between `View` and `Fragment`) altogether.

Comment: If you look at the answer I supplied earlier that exactly what I did. Thank you for your help.