# How to get instance of view's parent fragment:

Tags: java, android, layout, casting, android-fragments

I have a fragment with an `XML` layout file. in it I have an 2 clickable `ImageView`s.
for each `ImageView` I set an `onClick` method for example: android:onClick="commentFragmentRemoveOnClick".

In the FragmentActivity (The Activity no the Fragment) I defined it this way:

```
public void commentFragmentRemoveOnClick(View v)
{

}
```

No this Fragment is of type `CommentFragment` and it has a `public void getFragmentTag()`method
to get it's tag that I save in earlier time. I need to get an instance of the fragment in which the image was clicked to get it's tag.

I tried:

```
((CommentFragment)v).getParentFragment().getFragmentTag();
```

and:

```
((CommentFragment)v).getParent().getFragmentTag();
```

but eclipse gives me error on both of them, how is this done properly?

To make it more clear this is my `CommentFragment`:

```
public class CommentFragment extends Fragment {

private final static String TAG = CommentFragment.class.getSimpleName(); 
private String fragmentTag;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_fragment_layout,
            container, false);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    String text = bundle.getString("comment");
    String fullUser = bundle.getString("user");
    String user = fullUser.substring(0, fullUser.indexOf("@"));
    String at = bundle.getString("at");

    TextView tvCmment = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvComment);
    TextView tvUser = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvUser);
    TextView tvAt = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);

    tvCmment.setText(text);
    tvUser.setText(user);
    tvAt.setText(at);

    return rootView;
}

public void setText(String item) 
{
    TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvComment);
    view.setText(item);
}

public void setFragmentTag(String tag)
{
    this.fragmentTag = tag;
}

public String getFragmentTag()
{
    return this.fragmentTag;
}
 }
```

and the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llCommentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@drawable/try2">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvUser"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvComment"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:background="@color/my_gray"
       android:text="demo"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:paddingLeft="5dp"
       android:paddingRight="5dp"    
       android:textColor="@color/my_even_darker_gray" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvComment"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/tvDate"
       android:padding="5dp"
       android:text="This task is described in more details if you click on it."
       android:textColor="@color/my_even_darker_gray" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvAt"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:paddingRight="5dp" 
       android:textColor="@color/my_even_darker_gray"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvUser"
       android:background="@color/my_gray"
       android:text="at" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvDate"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvAt"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvAt"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvAt"
       android:background="@color/my_gray"
       android:text="12/02"
       android:textColor="@color/my_even_darker_gray" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvComment"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/add_comment_button"
        android:onClick="commentFragmentEditOnClick"
        android:src="@drawable/add_comment_button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iRemove"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iEdit"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iEdit"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/add_comment_button"
        android:onClick="commentFragmentRemoveOnClick"
        android:src="@drawable/add_comment_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would love for a little assistance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a general advice for you that would solve your problem and help you in the future -

1. don't use android:onClick in the xml file, use setOnClickListener in the code itself - need to avoid mixing your views with other parts of the app as much as possible.
2. Try to keep the Fragment independent of its activity.

If the image is part of the fragment, why does the listener is part of the FragmentActivity?

Use setOnClickListener in the fragment itself, and you might be able to use this Framgent in other pats of the app without being depended on the Activity.

It would also solve your problem of identifying the fragment in which the image was clicked.

Comment: Thanks @Pinhassi, but if you look at the code a supplied yesterday as an answer, that exactly what I did. but thanks again for your help and Hag sameah : )

Answer (score 3):

v is not an instance of `Fragment`, that's why Eclipse does not like your code. If you want the instance of a fragment you have to use the `FragmentManager` and one of its findFragmentByXXX methods.

Comment: I know v is not a fragment, v is a ImageView inside of a fragment, I need to get the instance of this fragment by this ImageView. My fragments are added dynamicly and have no id's. they only have tags which i assign to them via the setFragmentTag and getFragmentTag which I'm tring to use right now.

Comment: In that case you use findFragmentByTag. Also, if you know v is not a fragment, why did you do `((CommentFragment)v)`?

Comment: You are not getting my question: To use findFragmentByTag method via FragmentManager I need to get instance of the fragment in which the view was clicked in , and from it extract it's assigned tag that I assigned to it earlier. And that's what I'm trying to do if you look carefully you will see that I am trying to get the parent of the click View, I only don't know exactly how it done.

Comment: Now I got it. So... a few tips: try to avoid using `android:onClick` and rather assign your click listeners manually. Also, if you have dynamically added fragments you can set the tag of the fragment to your image views. That way, if you want the fragment tag of the fragment containing the clicked `ImageView` you just have to do `v.getTag()`

Comment: A little more background: if you look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484530/removing-editing-fragments-that-were-add-dynamically it might be more clear what I'm trying to achieve. and please look at the question again, I have added code. So if I set the Tag to the ImageView I still have to use the getFragmentTag method. is there no way to get it's instance? it's the container of the view that I am clicking on, there must a connection between them I can use.

Answer (score 0):

To get the instance of the fragment that the `ImageView` was clicked in I did the following:

in the Fragment I set two `onClickListeners` for both of the images like this:

```
    iEdit = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.iEdit);
    iEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "pressed edit button");
            ((PicturesAndCommentsActivity) getActivity()).commentFragmentEditOnClick(fragmentTag);
        }
    });

    iRemove = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.iRemove);
    iRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "pressed remove button");
            ((PicturesAndCommentsActivity) getActivity()).commentFragmentRemoveOnClick(fragmentTag);
        }
    });
```

and in the fragment activity I defined those two methods like this:

```
public void commentFragmentRemoveOnClick (String tag)
{
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.remove(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)).commit();
}
```

for removing the fragment, and Now I'm working on editing the fragment.